# Using operators in variable/array - VBS

Tags: variables, vbscript, operators

Is it possible to use a mathematical operator in a variable?

**TL;DR version:**
I'm playing around in VBS and was wondering if it's possible to create a script that would give you the operator as a result of a mathematical equation, but can't store the operator in a variable to test it.

example:

```
3 ? 4 = 12
```

the result should be:

```
"*"
```

**Long version:**
What I'm actually trying to do is find out all possible results of an equation within a given range:

example:

given that

```
0 < X < 21  
0 < Y < 21  
a, b, c = {"+", "-", "*", "/"}
```

I want to get all possible results of the following equation

```
X a Y b X c Y = 10
```

What I do, is run multiple for loops inside each other and check for every possible outcomes. However I can't figure out how to insert the operators into arrays.

what I got so far:

```
Dim x
Dim y

for i = 1 to 20
x = i
    for j = 1 to 20
    y = j

        if x + y + x + y = 10 then msgbox x & " " & y

    next

next
```

Comment: Try This : `WSH.Echo (5 + 8)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is doable by building a string with the desired expression and then using [`Eval`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//0z5x4094%28v%3dvs.85%29) to evaluate it:

```
X = 3
Y = 6
a = "+"

expr = X & " " & a & " " & Y

WScript.Echo Eval(expr)  'output: 9
```

Runtime evaluation of code can cause all kinds of problems, though, so be very careful what you're using this for.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! :)
What kind of problems are you referring to?

Comment: @Divin3 [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/11/01/eval-is-evil-part-one/) and [that](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/11/04/eval-is-evil-part-two/). While the examples are implemented in JavaScript, the issues apply to VBScript as well.